# Angular2 Provider that depends on other Providers

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular-providers

I have several modules within my Angular2 application, that provide Services and Configuration.

Now I'd like to include the `@ngrx/store` which collects the available reducers from my modules.

---

Here's the bootstrap code:

```
import {OpaqueToken} from 'angular2/core'
import {provideStore} from '@ngrx/store'

export const REDUCER_TOKEN = new OpaqueToken('Reducer');

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    provide(REDUCER_TOKEN, { useClass: Module1Reducers, multi: true }),
    provide(REDUCER_TOKEN, { useClass: Module2Reducers, multi: true }),
    // old code: provideStore({module1, module2}, {module1:{}, module2:[]})
    provideStore(/* INSERT CODE HERE */)
]);
```

---

The `INSERT CODE HERE` comment should be replaced with something, that uses all `REDUCER_TOKEN` providers.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you see `provide(REDUCER_TOKEN, ...)`? That's a provider that can be used along with `@Inject(REDUCER_TOKEN) list:MyInterface[]`. Have a look here ( http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular2/2015/11/23/multi-providers-in-angular-2.html ), section *Understanding Multi Providers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a way to pass it to `provideStore()` directly.

`provideStore` creates and returns an array of providers. 
My attempt is to first add the providers `provideStore()` creates and then in a second step override the `REDUCER` that depends on `REDUCER_TOKEN`:

```ts
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    provide(REDUCER_TOKEN, { useClass: Module1Reducers, multi: true }),
    provide(REDUCER_TOKEN, { useClass: Module2Reducers, multi: true }),
    // add generated providers
    provideStore(),
    // override `REDUCER` provider
    provide(REDUCER, {
      deps: [REDUCER_TOKEN],
      useFactory(reducer){
        if(typeof reducer === 'function'){
          return reducer;
        }

        return combineReducers({
            "foo":reducer[0].reducerFunction, 
            "bar":reducer[1].reducerFunction
        });
      }
    }),
]);
```

If multiple providers are added for the same token (or type), without `multi: true`, then only the one added last takes effect.

Built according to this `provideStore()` implementation https://github.com/ngrx/store/blob/master/src/ng2.ts#L56

-- not tested --

Comment: Thank you! I now tested it, and it works with some small change: In `useFactory(reducer)` the `reducer` is an array: `[Module1, Module2]`. But the `combineReducers` function, will only take functions as parameter. Though for getting nice store names, you got to build an object from the `reducers` array. In the end, the parameter passed to `combineReducers` should look like this: `{"foo":reducer[0].reducerFunction, "bar":reducer[1].reducerFunction}` (where `foo` and `bar` are the store names). `...` anyways: You solved it! Thank you.

Comment: Looks good, in my code I use a more dynamic solution, where I get the `name` and the `reducerFunction` from the module array. Like this: `return combineReducers(reducer.reduce((o, v) => { o[v.name] = v.reducerFunction; return o; }, {}));`. But your code is fine as well :)

Comment: Great. I'll leave it as is then, your comment will stay here anyway.